# Creating a date and finding time difference in an Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having some trouble finding the length of experience using an incomplete date in my table. I have it working for finding someone's age, but I have not been sucessful in calculating their length of experience.

The grad year is just a four digit year, so we are calculating as if they graduated on 1/1/YYYY. But everything I have tried is not working.

```
SELECT userID, 
birthdate,
to_char((sysdate-birthdate)/365.25,'00.00')  as Age,
graduationYear,
to_char((sysdate-??????)/365.25,'00.00')  as Experience
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT userID, 
       birthdate,
       to_char((sysdate-birthdate)/365.25,'00.00')  as Age,
       graduationYear,
       to_char((sysdate-TO_DATE(to_char(graduationYear)||'-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))/365.25,'00.00')  as Experience
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: In some of the results I have ##### showing up instead of a number, but it appears to have a valid number in the data. What would cause that?

Comment: hard to say without knowing the schema, and have a sample of the data that is doing this.